# Инжектирование Dagger в Activity

Tags: android, dagger2

Читая статью [Using Dagger in Android apps](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android), наткнулась на следующие строки:

> When using activities, inject Dagger in the activity's onCreate()
>   method before calling super.onCreate() to avoid issues with fragment
>   restoration. During the restore phase in super.onCreate(), an activity
>   attaches fragments that might want to access activity bindings.

И меня это удивило, потому что я всегда использовала

```
someComponent.inject(this)
```

после `super.onCreate()` в activity. И в связи с этим возникли вопросы: какие проблемы с восстановлением фрагментов можно избежать, если инжектировать даггер перед `super.onCreate()`? И что значит фраза "fragments that might want to access activity bindings"? Было бы здорово, если бы кто-нибудь смог пояснить это на примерах кода...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это означает, что во время `Fragment.onAttach()` фрагмент может захотеть данные инжектированные в `Activity`, соответственно возникнет крах, поскольку иньекции данных в `Activity` еще не было (еще не вызван `inject()`)

Если фрагменту не нужны такие данные, то можно спокойно вызывать `inject()` после `super.onCreate()`